# Build a Json file from python dictionary and nested dictionary/list

Tags: python, json

I am having hard time to build a json file.
That should look like:

```
{'January': 
     [ {'week 1' : 
        [ {'day 1': [{'birthday_name': 'Stack', 'lastname': 'hector'},{'birthday_name': 'Stack', 'lastname': 'hector'},
          {'day 2': [{'birthday_name': 'Vlad', 'lastname': 'Overflow'},{'birthday_name': 'Exchange', 'lastname': 'Other'} ]
        }
      ],
     [ {'week 2' : 
        [ {'day 1': [{'birthday_name': 'Stack', 'lastname': 'hector'},{'birthday_name': 'Stack', 'lastname': 'hector'},
          {'day 2': [{'birthday_name': 'Vlad', 'lastname': 'Overflow'},{'birthday_name': 'Exchange', 'lastname': 'Other'} ]
        }
      ]
 }
```

I have this code for now, but since I am building when the loop occurs there is value that do not exist yet like month, week and day. 
I am trying with if statement to check if the dictionnary value exist, if yes continue down the tree and check if there is the week and the day if yes to all three then append the value.
If not for each of them I create the value in the dictionary/list to make it available to fill then the data.

And now I get error code 'KeyError'. (value does not exist in dictionary)

here is the code for now.

```
final_list = {}

for i in friends:
    friends_name = i['SUMMARY'][16:]
    friends_bdate = i['DTSTART']
    month_bday = int(i['DTSTART'][4:6])
    day_bday = int(i['DTSTART'][6:8])
    week_number = datetime.date(2015, month_bday, day_bday).isocalendar()[1]


    if final_list[month_bday]:
        if final_list[month_bday][week_number]:
            if final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday]:
                final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday].append({'name': friends_name, 'bdate': friends_bdate, 'pic' : friends_picture})
            else:
                final_list[month_bday] = [{week_number: [{day_bday: []}]}]
                final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday].append({'name': friends_name, 'bdate': friends_bdate, 'pic' : friends_picture})
        else:
            final_list[month_bday] = [{week_number: []}]
            if final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday] :
                final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday].append({'name': friends_name, 'bdate': friends_bdate, 'pic' : friends_picture})
            else:
                final_list[month_bday] = [{week_number: [{day_bday: []}]}]
                final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday].append({'name': friends_name, 'bdate': friends_bdate, 'pic' : friends_picture})
    else:
        final_list[month_bday] = {month_bday : []}
        if final_list[month_bday][week_number]:
            if final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday]:
                final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday].append({'name': friends_name, 'bdate': friends_bdate, 'pic' : friends_picture})
            else:
                final_list[month_bday] = [{week_number: [{day_bday: []}]}]
                final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday].append({'name': friends_name, 'bdate': friends_bdate, 'pic' : friends_picture})
        else:
            final_list[month_bday] = [{week_number: []}]
            if final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday] :
                final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday].append({'name': friends_name, 'bdate': friends_bdate, 'pic' : friends_picture})
            else:
                final_list[month_bday] = [{week_number: [{day_bday: []}]}]
                final_list[month_bday][week_number][day_bday].append({'name': friends_name, 'bdate': friends_bdate, 'pic' : friends_picture})
```

edit: the others variable are:
friends_name = 'Tony'
friends_bday = '20150516'

Thank for Daniel answer I just changed this

```
final_list = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {}))
```

to

```
final_list = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {})))
```

link to defaultdict function.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Please specify the other variables like friends,etc.?

Comment: `final_list` is an empty dict, yet you're trying to access `if final_list[month_bday]:`?

Comment: Do your really want lists with only 1 element?

Comment: why not check for the key before you try to access it?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal, I updated the other variables. Rawing I was trying to check if the value in the dict exist if not then create it.

Comment: The fix fix by @Daniel didn't worked for you ?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal yes it worked just updated it for next person will have all details in hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `defaultdict`s and `datetime.strptime`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
final_list = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {}))

for friend in friends:
    friends_name = friend['SUMMARY'][16:]
    friends_bdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(friend['DTSTART'], '%Y%m%d')
    week_number = friends_bdate.replace(year=2015).isocalendar()[1]
    final_list[friends_bdate.month][week_number][friends_bdate.day] = {
        'name': friends_name, 'bdate': friend['DTSTART'], 'pic' : friends_picture
    }
```

Comment: thank you ! I only an additional lambda (for day value), final_list = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {})))